# Error while deploying ear

Tags: java, deployment, ejb

While deploying the ear, I am getting the error below.  I'm not sure what is causing this error.  Can someone help me with this?

> SharedEJBRunt E WSVR0040E: addEjbModule failed for PCPTimerService.jar com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: Bean class com.citi.gwm.custody.services.PCPStartUpBean could not be found or loaded

Comment: it seams that you use this class `com.citi.gwm.custody.services.PCPStartUpBean` but not exist in your package `com.citi.gwm.custody.services`, can you please check if exit or not?

Comment: The reason seems clear: the mentioned bean could not be found or loaded. This could be due to something else (like configuration) trying to access/load that bean or due to a problem with loading the bean itself (look for related errors or warnings).

Comment: Exactly what it says: this one `PCPStartUpBean` can't be found (on the classpath). First I'd check which library should have it and if that library is inside the ear file.